# Storing relational data in objects, overwrites values

Tags: objective-c

I apologize for the lengthy question, ill try demonstrating the problem with examples.

I have three objects

> 1. Disease
> 2. Compound
> 3. Comdis

I am storing the list of Diseases and Compounds in respective classes.

The relations between Compounds and Diseases are to be stored in a list of objects called Comdis, Comdis stores pairs of (COMPOUND,DISEASE).

The example infromation that is to be stored in objects are.

```
DISEASES
index  acronim  fullname
1        AML,      Acute Myelogenous Leukemia
2        PV,       Polycytemia Vera
3        MF,       Mielofibrosis

COMPOUNDS
index  acronim    fullname
1       LBH589,   Panobinostat
2       INC424,   Ruxolitinib
3       BKM120,   Buparsinib

RELATIONS (COMDIS)
index  disease  compound
1        ( 0   ,    1 )
2        ( 0   ,    2 )
3        ( 0   ,    3 )
4        ( 1   ,    1 )
5        ( 1   ,    2 )
6        ( 1   ,    3 )
7        ( 2   ,    1 )
8        ( 2   ,    2 )
9        ( 2   ,    3 )
```

> **My disease.h looks like this.**

```
@interface disease: NSObject
{
    NSString __strong *acronim;
    NSString __strong *fullname;
    int backcolor;
    UIImage __strong *background;
}
@property (nonatomic) int backcolor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *background;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *acronim;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *fullname;
@property NSMutableArray *list;
- (id)initWithDiseaseList;
- (int)getIndexByAcronim:(NSString *)acronim;
@end
```

> **disease.m has the following code**

```
#import "disease.h"

@implementation disease

@synthesize acronim, fullname, backcolor, background;

-(id)initWithDiseaseList {
    disease *aml = [[disease alloc] init];
    [aml setAcronim:@"AML"];
    [aml setFullname:@"Acute Myelogenous Leukemia"];
    disease *pv = [[disease alloc] init];
    [pv setAcronim:@"PV"];
    [pv setFullname:@"Polycytemia Vera"];
    disease *mf = [[disease alloc] init];
    [mf setAcronim:@"MF"];
    [mf setFullname:@"Mielofibrosis"];
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [array addObject:aml];
    [array addObject:pv];
    [array addObject:mf];
    self.list = array;
    return self;
}
- (int)getIndexByAcronim:(NSString *)accr {
    NSArray *array = self.list;
    for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
        disease *disease = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        if(disease.acronim == accr) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
@end
```

my compound.m is very similar to disease object.

now in comdis i want to store relations.

> **my comdis.h looks like this**

```
@interface comdis: NSObject
{
    int *icompound;
    int *idisease;
}
@property (nonatomic,) int *icompound;
@property (nonatomic,) int *idisease;
@property NSMutableArray *list;
- (id)initWithComdisList;
@end
```

> **and this is my comdis.m**

```
#import "comdis.h"
#import "compound.h"
#import "disease.h"
@implementation comdis
@synthesize idisease, icompound;

- (id)initWithComdisList {
    compound *comp = [[compound alloc] initWithCompoundList];
    disease   *dis = [[disease alloc] initWithDiseaseList];
    NSArray *compoundArray = comp.list;
    NSArray *diseaseArray = dis.list;

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 0; i < [diseaseArray count]; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < [compoundArray count]; j++) {
            int iCompoundIndex = [compoundArray indexOfObject:compoundArray[j]];
            int iDiseaseIndex  = [diseaseArray indexOfObject:diseaseArray[i]];
            comdis *com = [[comdis alloc] init];
            [com setIdisease:&iDiseaseIndex];
            [com setIcompound:&iCompoundIndex];
            [array addObject:com];
        }
    }
    comdis *comdisObj = [self.list objectAtIndex:1];
    int idis = *(comdisObj.idisease);
    int icom = *(comdisObj.icompound);

    NSLog(@"%d", idis);
    NSLog(@"%d", icom);    
    return self;
}
@end
```

The problem is if i try printing the value of `idis` or `icom` it always prints `2` regardless of `objectAtIndex` value i give. it seems the value in loop is being overwritten and it always takes the last value of loop, i am a beginner to objective-c and will appreciate if someone could put some light on what is wrong with my code.

Sorry again for lengthy explanation and code.

Comment: I see this can be solved in 5 minutes using CoreData !!!

Comment: @AnoopVaidya any hint or any possible solution?

Comment: Can you please share your question, in terms of class diagram or even by words. NO code please, there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[com setIdisease:&iDiseaseIndex];`Because all comdis object's property disease and compound refer to the same address, they all equal to the value of last added object. To overcome this problem, you may use *int* property instead of ***int** in comdis.